# Passing and Receiving variables using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I know the basics about passing data using `Intent`, but there seems to be a problem on my code. I cant receive it. I don't know if the problem occurs in passing or receiving.

This is my code:

In Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowScore.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Score",score);
bundle.putSerializable("QnA",g);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

And on the receiving end (which is Activity B):

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
Int Score = b.getInt("Score");
String [][] QnA = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("QnA");
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: which values aren't you getting ? Is it that int value or the serializable value or both ? and moreover what is g which you put as serializable ?

Comment: @shuvro g is a bidimensional String array. I am not really sure that im not getting both, because i am only displaying the score on the next activity, but I am sure that I'm not getting the score because the TextView which is suppose to change, wont change.

Comment: @Zarwan there is no error, that's what surprises me, because the score is suppose to display on activity B, but it wont. there is no error though, thats why I'm confused.

Comment: @KNeerajLal thank you for that reference, but I already know how to pass 2D arrays.

Comment: I mean what value is not coming through? Your code looks fine to me. It is probably something else.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Any obesrvations?

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
Changes here int Score = b.getInt("Score");
             String [][] QnA = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("QnA");
```

You wrote bundle instead of b. 
Cheers!

Comment: LOL! Thanks alot. i was puzzled there for a moment. i wonder tho, how come i didnt get any erros?

Comment: @DanBrianArenas, LOL.(y)

Comment: my code was right. i was only wrong on the code i posted. still cant get my int and String array. :( I edited my question already. sorry for that.

Comment: rewrite the full activity, both activity in the question

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my android studio wasn't detecting any changes on my codes. I uninstalled the app from my device and tried to run it again. the problem was on my android studio not detecting the changes i've made. Thank you for all your answers and comments. It was not a code problem after all.